Next.js Context not update data(localStorage)
guys! I write my program and now i create context, for getting eady data. So i have a problem when i do router.push, then i return to another page(after return i update my jwt token). I this page which i returned i use my context to get data, but its say that localStorage is null. So context dont update localStorage data for him. There is my context code:`
'use client';
const GetDataContext = createContext(null);

export function ContextProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const jwt = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt");
          const instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: links.url,
            timeout: 1000,
            headers: { 'Authorization': jwt }
          });
  
          const response = await instance.get('/api/user/data');
          setData(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
          setData("notAuthorized")
        }
      };
  
      fetchData();
    }, []);

  return (
    <GetDataContext.Provider value={data}>
      {children}
    </GetDataContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(GetDataContext);
}

and a page where i return:
const data = useAppContext();
useEffect(() => {
  if (data === "notAuthorized") {
    console.log('yes')
  }
}, [data])

I try to solve problem with chatgpt and try to search this problem in some sites, but i dont get information to solve this problem
